# Is the null space of matrix $A$ same as null space of matrix $S_A$ if $S_A=\operatorname{rref}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A\in \Bbb M_{m\times n}$ and if $S_A=\operatorname{rref}(A)$, then $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(S_A)$. True or not?

I know that from RREF we can find wich columns are linearly independent, so that form helps a lot to find out  connections between columns of matrix $A$. Knowing all this, can I say that they will have the same null spaces?

Comment: What is rref? row-reduced echelon form? Thus obtained from $A$ by only row operations?

Answer (score 0):

$S_A$ is obtained from $A$ by elementary row operations, i.e., by left multiplying $A$ with an invertible matrix: $S_A=BA$ where $B$ is invertible. Then 
$$ v\in\ker A\implies Av=0\implies S_Av=BAv=B0=0\implies v\in \ker S_A$$
and 
$$ v\in\ker S_A\implies S_Av=0\implies Av=B^{-1}S_Av=B^{-1}0=0\implies v\in \ker A.$$

Answer (score 0):

The null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space. Elementary row operations *reversibly* (that’s very important) replace rows of the matrix with linear combinations of rows of the matrix, so they don’t change the row space. Therefore...